# How to convert SVG to BMP in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, svg, wxpython, bmp

I'm trying to convert svg to bmp, for further processing (custom qr-code)
I found that I need to do this:

```
import cairosvg
import wx
import io

png = cairosvg.svg2png(url="test.svg", write_to="test.png")
img = wx.Image(io.StringIO(png),wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
bmp = wx.Bitmap(img)
```

Debug said:

```
18:34:58: Error: This is not a PNG file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "svg2bmp5.py", line 7, in <module>
bmp = wx.Bitmap(img)
wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

But the "test.png" was created by cairosvg.
Help me please..

Rolf of Saxony suggested adding target of bmp: I want achieve jast only *.bmp-file for further pass it in "potrace".
I need it for making custom qr-code.

Example:
[image: custom QR-code]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what you are trying to achieve with the wxPython part of the code.
If you simply want to display it, try the following:

```
import cairosvg
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        cairosvg.svg2png(url="test.svg", write_to="test.png")
        img = wx.Image('test.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.Bitmap(img))
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(self.Image, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

You should not use `io.StringIO()` on `png` because `cairosvg.svg2png(url="test.svg", write_to="test.png")` creates a file, therefore `png` is actually `None`, not an image.
Remember `print( your problem )` in this case `png`, is your friend. It will tell you what the thing is. For added clarity, use `print(repr( xx ))` or `print(type( xx ))`

Edit:
Based on your comment the following might help:

```
import cairosvg
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        cairosvg.svg2png(url="test.svg", write_to="test.png")
        img = wx.Image('test.png')
        img.ConvertAlphaToMask(255,255,255)
        bmp = wx.Bitmap(img)
        self.Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=bmp)
        self.Image.Bitmap.SaveFile('test.bmp', type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(self.Image, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Involves removing the transparency from the png file before saving as a bmp, or the whole thing is one giant black blob.
Your example image really should be the .svg image not a .png

Comment: I need bmp save it in file for further processing in "potrace". Thank You. I add explanation to the quastion.

Comment: See my edited answer. Perhaps you could replace the example png file with the actual svg file. It would make testing easier.